# Why does SQL Server struggle with this query but MS Access doesn't?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, query-optimization, ms-access-2016, sql-server-2019

In MS Access, this query is structured the same way and pulls from the same tables. The only catch is that `V_JOB_HEADER` is a remote table on a different server. In MS Access, this is set up as a linked table. In SQL Server, it's queried via `OPENQUERY`.

The remote table is a table for an ERP product called Global Shop Solutions.

MS Access: 2 seconds

SQL Server: 2 minutes

The only way I could explain this huge processing time difference is if maybe Access was caching the results of the remote table, but the speed persists even if I close and reopen the Access database! So if there is caching going on, it's somehow "permanently" caching the data somewhere...

```
if object_id('tempdb..#VJOBHEADER') is not null drop table #VJOBHEADER

--#VJOBHEADER 
select 

    *

into #VJOBHEADER

from

    openquery(GSS, 'select * from V_JOB_HEADER') t --1 min 27 seconds; 
    
select

    p.*

from

    [Production Order] p with(nolock)
    left join #VJOBHEADER v on p.JOB = v.JOB and p.SUFFIX = v.SUFFIX

where

    v.JOB is null
    and p.Status not in ('CLOSED','COMPLETE','STOCKED')
    and left(p.Status, 7) <> 'SHIPPED'
    and left(p.[PrO Number], 1) not in ('A','B')

if object_id('tempdb..#VJOBHEADER') is not null drop table #VJOBHEADER
```

**Connection string for linked table in Access:**

> ODBC;DSN=GLOBAL_APT;ServerName=SERVERNAME.1583;UID=COMPANYNAME;ArrayFetchOn=1;ArrayBufferSize=8;TransportHint=TCP;DBQ=GLOBALAPT           ;OpenMode=0;ClientVersion=14.21.010.000;CodePageConvert=1252;PvClientEncoding=CP1252;PvServerEncoding=CP1252;AutoDoub;TABLE=V_JO

(Note - for some reason Access cuts off the full name of the linked table in the connection string above, not sure why)

Comment: How do you execute this in Access? That is not valid SQL for Access query object.

Comment: For query performance questions, we need at a minimum: the table *and index* definitions, and please share the query plan via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan. The question is not answerable otherwise. You probably need better indexing, but without telling us what you have we can't help.

Comment: `left(p.Status, 7) <> 'SHIPPED'` should probably be `p.Status NOT LIKE 'SHIPPED%'` and `left(p.[PrO Number], 1) not in ('A','B')` should probably be `(p.[PrO Number] not like 'A% and p.[PrO Number] not like 'B%')` and then you probably are going to want an index `#VJOBHEADER (JOB, SUFFIX)` You also want to change that `left join is null` into a `not exists`. Also `nolock` is not a go-faster switch, it can cause incorrect results, don't use it unless you know what you're doing

Comment: @Charlieface woah woah wait a minute what's this about `nolock`? I've never heard that. I use it so that my reports don't lock the table so that more important processes can take priority in doing a write/delete. Reporting should not slow down my system, so much so that I am willing to let the database change at the same time that I'm pulling data from it. Is that what you were talking about or is there some other known issue with `nolock`?

Comment: No shortage of reading material here: https://sqlblog.org/nolock

Comment: Also https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2021/11/nolock-is-bad-and-you-probably-shouldnt-use-it/ and https://blog.coeo.com/using-with-nolock-read-this and https://redmondmag.com/articles/2022/01/21/understanding--dirty-reads.aspx and https://sqlperformance.com/2015/04/t-sql-queries/the-read-uncommitted-isolation-level

Comment: The real solution to performance problems is either: if you have noone else using the same system then just force `TABLOCK` on everything and lock the whole table. Or if others are using it then use `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SNAPSHOT` which also prevents blocking problems but doesn't have the same issues.

Comment: A 60x difference in reading the same data from the same source? Seems like a network issue. Is the SQL Server instance running on the same machine as Access? If not then it could be taking an entirely different path across the internet to get to GSS. Same ODBC driver versions installed on the SQL Server as on the Access machine?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning the SQL Server instance was me running a query in SSMS directly on the server where our main SQL database lives and pulling data from GSS. The MS Access one was on my VM. Where would I check the ODBC versions?